AWS SDK (Boto3) create_vpc_attachment` call fails with "Incorrect input" when passing valid parameters
I'm using AWS SDK (Boto3) to create a VPC attachment to a core network using the create_vpc_attachment API. However, I keep receiving the following error:
Error creating VPC attachment: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateVpcAttachment operation: Incorrect input.
Here is my code:
def create_vpc_attachment(network_manager_client, core_network_id, vpc_id, subnet_arns, region, account_id, poll_interval=60, max_retries=20):
    retries = 0
    try:
        # Ensure the correct ARN format for VPC
        vpc_arn = f'arn:aws:ec2:{region}:{account_id}:vpc/{vpc_id}'
        
        # Fetch existing VPC attachments for the specified region
        existing_attachments = network_manager_client.list_attachments(
            CoreNetworkId=core_network_id,
            AttachmentType='VPC',
            EdgeLocation=region
        )

        match_found = False 

        # Check if any existing attachments are found
        if existing_attachments.get('Attachments'):

            for attachment in existing_attachments['Attachments']:
                if attachment['ResourceArn'] == vpc_arn:
                    match_found = True
                    attachment_id = attachment['AttachmentId']
                    state = attachment['State']

                    # If VPC is already attached and available, return the state
                    if state == 'AVAILABLE':
                        logger.info(f"VPC {vpc_id} is already attached with ID: {attachment_id} in state {state}.")
                        return state
                    else:
                        logger.info(f"VPC {vpc_id} is  {state}.")
                        return state
                    
            if not match_found:
                logger.info(f"No matching attachment found for VPC {vpc_id}. Proceeding to create a new attachment.")

        if not match_found:
            # No existing attachment found, proceed to create a new one
            try:
                logger.info("Creating a VPC attachment.")

                # Log all the input parameters to ensure they are correct
                logger.info(f"CoreNetworkId: {core_network_id}")
                logger.info(f"VpcArn: {vpc_arn}")
                logger.info(f"SubnetArns: {subnet_arns}")

                response = network_manager_client.create_vpc_attachment(
                    CoreNetworkId=core_network_id,
                    VpcArn=vpc_arn,
                    SubnetArns=subnet_arns,
                    Options={'Ipv6Support': False},
                    Tags=[
                        {'Key': 'Env', 'Value': 'prod'},
                        {'Key': 'Name', 'Value': f'{account_id}-attachment-{vpc_id}'}
                    ]
                )

                # Extract the newly created VPC attachment details
                vpc_attachment = response.get('VpcAttachment', {})
                attachment = vpc_attachment.get('Attachment', {})
                attachment_id = attachment.get('AttachmentId')
                state = attachment.get('State')

            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(f"Error creating VPC attachment: {e}")
                sys.exit(1)

            while retries < max_retries:
                try:
                    # Fetch the current VPC attachment status
                    response = network_manager_client.get_vpc_attachment(AttachmentId=attachment_id)
                    attachment = response['VpcAttachment']['Attachment']
                    state = attachment.get('State')

                    logger.info(f"Current attachment state: {state}")

                    if state == 'AVAILABLE':
                        logger.info(f"VPC {attachment_id} is now AVAILABLE.")
                        return state  # Return the successful attachment details
                    elif state == 'FAILED':
                        logger.error(f"VPC {attachment_id} failed. Exiting.")
                        sys.exit(1)

                    # Sleep for the specified poll interval before checking again
                    time.sleep(poll_interval)
                    retries += 1

                except Exception as e:
                    logger.error(f"Error while checking attachment state: {e}")
                    sys.exit(1)

            logger.error(f"Max retries reached. VPC Attachment {attachment_id} is still not 'AVAILABLE'.")
            sys.exit(1)

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error creating VPC attachment: {e}")
        logger.error(f"Full exception: {str(e)}")
        sys.exit(1)

I've tested all of the variables and arns, output example is:
INFO - CoreNetworkId: core-network-*
INFO - VpcArn: arn:aws:ec2:myregion:*:vpc/vpc-*
INFO - SubnetArns: ['arn:aws:ec2:myregion:*:subnet/subnet-1*',  'arn:aws:ec2:myregion:*:subnet/subnet-2*','arn:aws:ec2:myregion:*:subnet/subnet-3*']
ERROR - Error creating VPC attachment: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateVpcAttachment operation: Incorrect input.

I've used in many places of the code corenetwork id - this value 100% correct.
Subnets arns retrieved from api call, that shouldn't be an issue.
only one thing is - I've generated vpc arn in the code.

"this value 100% correct" any piece of software can have flaws, but I have a lot of confidence in boto3, and sympathy for how hard it can be to find subtle AWS  input issues with vague error messages like that.   If you can't figure out why boto won't do it, try taking boto out of the equation and do it at the command line.  Or, do it in the console, then check cloudtrail to see what the operation looked like.

['arn:aws:ec2:myregion:*:subnet/subnet-1*',  'arn:aws:ec2:myregion:*:subnet/subnet-2*','arn:aws:ec2:myregion:*:subnet/subnet-3*'] in what sense are these valid subnet ARNs?  I'm sure you're obfuscating it, but those are where to look.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/networkmanager/latest/APIReference/API_CreateVpcAttachment.html. To me the VPC arn looks right, but humans are poor parsers.

Hi
erik258
i found source of the issue - core network and vpc which should be attached was in different accounts, in the same account code is working as expected, thanks for your help)

Ouch, agree that "Incorrect input" from the EC2/VPC API is not a helpful error message.

During troubleshooting, I noticed that using the AWS CLI instead of Boto3 gave slightly different output. I tried running the script within the same account for both the EC2 client and Network Manager, and it worked. It seems Boto3 is performing a check to ensure that the core network and VPC are in the same account, but it's throwing an incorrect error, indicating a "wrong input."
